# Visual Studio 2010 - TFS - Work offline also TFS server is available

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, offline

I'm working in a big project in Visual Studio 2010. Often I must wait the check-in before doing simple test. How can I work with Visual Studio 2010 offline when TFS Server is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question 100%, but there are a couple of options depending on what you mean.

First of all, working offline is not possible with TFS 2010, but is available with local workspaces in TFS 2012 (overview in [this article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/02/local-workspaces-in-tfs-2012.aspx))

You say that you're waiting for check-in to complete. If you have a plain check-in situtation, then you have a couple of choices:

- You can open a second instance of Visual Studio, and work while the first instance completes the check-in.
- You can open a command prompt and use `tf.exe checkin` in your workspace directory.

If you have a gated check-in, then you can check the 'Preserve my pending changes locally', and you will be able to keep working on the changes until they have been validated and checked in. (further details in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patcarna/archive/2009/06/29/an-introduction-to-gated-check-in.aspx))

All that being said. A simple check-in should not take more than seconds. So if you're waiting a long time for a normal check-in situation, then you might have some performance/server issues.

Comment: thanks for your answer and sorry for my bad English. My problem is exactly this:I want modify a .cs file without check-out otherwise I want leave avaible this file. 

First of all, working offline is not possible with TFS 2010, but is available with local workspaces in TFS 2012 (overview in this article)

You answered me.

Thanks, Marco